# Can't control knee in blender 2.92

Tags: rigify

I'm new to blender. I want to make some animation using rig. When moving `foot_ik.L`, the knee has strange behavior. I Have searched and viewed some `Youtube` videos then I noticed I am doing something wrong. I found [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suP14lYWpN8) as most relevant video to my issue.

I tried to remove red-marked bones(first image) in order to add `pole bone` but can't select them(can't select red-marked, but can select green marked bones).

Note: Edit > Lock Object Modes is deactivated

Please guide me for this approach or offer better solution.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you're use Rigify for a human character there is no need to add or remove bones to have the knees working. How have you laid out the bones of the meta rig?

Comment: I just used scale and move to match metarig to mesh. Those two bones are generated automatically and is child of rig. So how to correct the knee position in second image?

Comment: Share your file. http://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching google and youtube found the solution finally. For those who may face this issue:

1- Select `metarig`
2- go to edit mode
3- rotate `thigh.L` and `thigh.R` (90 degree in my case)
4- go back to pose mode
5- under `Object Data Properties` > `Rigify Buttons` activate `Advanced Options` then `Overwrite` then click on `Generate Rig`

If any bone has problem for generating rig:
1- copy the bone name
2- remove it
3- create exact same bone(start and end points are important)
4- set parent
5- set children
6- set the name again
7- rigify again

Don't forget to apply transforms before any generations specially for `rigify`!

[image]
[image]